# Rspec and Watir; locating and changing <span> text within a button element

Tags: html, rspec, automation, watir-webdriver

I am playing around with rpsec and watir-webdriver, and am encountering a strange issue where I can click *into* a button, but I cannot interact with (or change) the text in the span inside. 
 This is what the html looks like:

```
<button class="pure-button toggle-mode button-link edit-text-button-element" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0" title="Edit">
    <span class="value false" data-reactid=".0.1.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0">Untitled</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

Right now my ruby code looks like this:

```
foo = @browser.button(:class, 'pure-button toggle-mode button-link edit-text-button-element')
foo.click
foo.span.set('Hello')
```

Running this gives me the initial error `expected Hash or (:how, 'what'), got ["Hello"]`

 Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works: after clicking to interact with the element, I was able to set text by using `send_keys`.  So I did this:

```
foo = @browser.button(:class, 'pure-button toggle-mode button-link edit-text-button-element')
foo.click
@browser.send_keys {keystrokes simulated here}
```

Comment: yep.  only elements of input type support the `.set` method.  So if this is a non-standard custom control, you need to use send-keys to emulate the user typing with focus on that element.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you cannot set text of the span in watir-webdriver. At least so easily. But if you will do for example:

```
puts foo.span.text
```

it will work. Here is the full list of what you can do with span: [Usefull Link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Span)

Of course there is the way to change the text in your span:

```
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent= 'Hello'", foo.span)
```

But I cannot imagine the situation when it will be really necessary for the real testing in a real world.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` locator only accepts a single class.

If you need all of the classes for it to be unique do:

`@browser.button(css: ".pure-button.toggle-mode.button-link.edit-text-button-element")`