# trying to update the text in a p tag using watir

Tags: html, ruby, google-chrome, watir

I am trying to automate entering some values on a website. There is a `<p>Home</p>` html line that I need to change to `<p>Accueil</p>` (that's french)

I have my script logging in, clicking some buttons to get to the page I need to be on, and then I get the paragraph tag using `f = browser.p(text: 'Home');` but I can't find anyway to change that text.

Update: I have tried "send_keys" and "execute_script" and they didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rspec and Watir; locating and changing <span> text within a button element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894212/rspec-and-watir-locating-and-changing-span-text-within-a-button-element)

Comment: I had seen that answer and it didn't help. Thanks, though.

Comment: If you're going to say *I tried x and it didn't work* then you should include what you've tried in your question, the outcome of that attempt, and why that didn't resolve the issue. I am assuming that it *does* work, because that's *how it works*, and if you're saying it doesn't then either 1) your question is unclear 2) you have an XY problem or 3) you didn't do it right.

Comment: You're right - I should have provided more of what exactly happened. I just went to do that, and realized that I think the page just isn't refreshing. When I get the p tag, I can have it print out it's "inner_text" and it shows "Home" and then when I use "execute_script", the page doesn't change, but if I get the p tag again, it shows "Accueil"
  f = browser.p(text: 'Home');
  puts f.inner_text
  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent= 'Hello'", f)
  f2 = browser.p(text: 'Hello')
  puts f2.inner_text

Comment: That helps. The issue isn't that the page isn't refreshing, the issue is that you've set a variable based on the content at the time you set the variable. If the underlying data changes then it doesn't also update the variable (which references the original state that you captured); you need to fetch the changed data and set it to a variable. (or set it to the same variable if you don't care about the original value)

Comment: I *am* fetching the changed data and setting it to "f2". but the html page still shows "Home" in that p tag.

Comment: Is it possible that there are 2 paragraphs with the text "Home"? The code is changing the 1st one on the page, but maybe the user actually sees the 2nd one on the page (which is unchanged by the code). Check if there are multiple on the page - `puts browser.ps(text: 'Home').count`

Answer (score -1):

Watir is designed for testing sites, not changing them. You'll need to use JavaScript for this:

```
element = browser.p(text: 'Home')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].textContent = "Accueil"', element)
```

Comment: Are we just copying and pasting from the duplicate question's answers rather than voting to close this question as a duplicate now?

Comment: The problem is that I have tried what the other answer has said, and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @anothermh Sorry, I didn't spend time trying to figure out if it was a duplicate or already had an answer. It's a quick answer so I gave it.

Comment: @atarihomestar the point is that you can't use the Watir API for this. If it isn't working for you, it is a JavaScript issue, not a Ruby or a Watir issue.